# Program to determine total stops taken by elevator

Tags: c#, algorithm

I was asked a question to write a optimal program that would determine the total number of stops a elevator has taken to serve X number of people. Question description is as below.

There is a elevator in a building with M floors, this elevator can take a max of X people at a time or max of total weight Y. Given that a set of people has arrived and their weight and the floor they need to stop given how many stops has the elevator taken to serve all the people. Consider elevator serves in the first come first serve basis.

E.g. Let Array A be the weight of people to be considered
A[] = {60, 80, 40 }

Let Array B be the floors where person needs to be dropped respectively
B[] = {2, 3, 5}

Total building floors be 5,max allowed person in elevator be 2 at a time with max weight capacity being 200
For this example the elevator would take total of 5 stops floors ground, 2, 3,ground, 5 , ground

What would be the optimal code for this?

One of my solution is as below. Is there any other better solutions?

```
class Solution
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return total stops used
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="A">weight of people</param>
    /// <param name="B">floors they need to get down</param>
    /// <param name="M">total floors in the building</param>
    /// <param name="X">Max people to carry at a time</param>
    /// <param name="Y">max weight to carry at a time</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int solution(int[] A, int[] B, int M, int X, int Y)
    {
        // write your code in C# 6.0 with .NET 4.5 (Mono)
        int totalStops = 0;
        long totalWeightPerRound = 0;
        int maxPersonsCount = 0;
        List<int> lstFloors = new List<int>();
        int currPerson = 0;
        bool startLift = false;
        while (currPerson < A.Length)
        {
            if ((totalWeightPerRound + A[currPerson]) <= Y && (maxPersonsCount+1) <= X)
            {
                totalWeightPerRound += A[currPerson];
                maxPersonsCount++;
                lstFloors.Add(B[currPerson]);
                if (currPerson == A.Length - 1)
                    startLift = true;

                currPerson++;
            }
            else
            {
                startLift = true;
            }

            if (startLift)
            {
                totalStops += lstFloors.Distinct().Count() + 1;
                lstFloors.Clear();
                maxPersonsCount = 0;
                totalWeightPerRound = 0;
                startLift = false;
            }
        }

        return totalStops;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself - what would be the optimal math \ algorithmic solution for it? How can you solve this problem, on paper, algorithmically, without programming language? When you answer this question - writing the code will be the easiest part.

Comment: I did write a solution, I updated it in my question but wanted to check if there is still better way of doing it.

Comment: It is not that good, and there are many little things to be improved. However, if this code works, then StackOverflow is not a place where people can help you. Please, refer to this article: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a code-review request.

Comment: Thanks I will post it on other site http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little off topic, but as someone said above, it`s a math not a programming question. To be on the safe side, you should construct a functional describing the cost function you want to minimize, add constraints to include boundary conditions and finally calculate the variation to get the extremum.

Putting it another way, it is a non trivial mathematical task and you should REALLY concentrate on getting the math right before even trying to write a line of code. To optimize means to get the optimal solution, not just some solution ;)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Please use the comments to post comments. If you do not have enough reputation to post a comment, please go get some reputation so that you can post a comment without violating the site's standards.